# Too fast to read result

Tags: c++, mfc, imagemagick

I have an issues with my code.
I want to execute the commande Line "convert.exe Capture.PNG Capture.bmp" which is in folder Utility.
So I want to create a process for it.

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
DWORD ExitCode;
ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
CString command="convert.exe "+CurrentDirectory()+"\\Utility\\Capture.PNG "+CurrentDirectory()+"\\Utility\\Capture.bmp >text.txt";
char test[1000];
memccpy(test,command,1,command.GetLength());
CString application=CurrentDirectory()+"\\Utility\\convert.exe";
if(CreateProcess(application, test,NULL,NULL,FALSE,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,NULL,NULL, &si, &pi))
{ 
    WaitForSingleObject(&pi.hProcess,INFINITE);
    printf("Yohoo!");
}  
else
{
    printf("The process could not be started...");
}
```

The program enter in the "if" but I dont have my bitmap.
I dont know how get the error write in the console. It closes itself very fast.

My code is in MFC C++ Visual Studio 2012... And convert.exe is the application from ImageMagick without installation.

thank you

Comment: Look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/333559/CreateProcess-and-wait-for-result this shows how to get a return code from the started process which might help debugging

Comment: Do note that Windows has a `convert` command, that may be executed instead of the ImageMagick `convert` (or whatever it is that you're using), e.g. if the `PATH` isn't quite right.

Comment: why not just use the standard library's `system`.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the statement

```
CString command="convert.exe "
    + CurrentDirectory() + "\\Utility\\Capture.PNG "
    + CurrentDirectory() + "\\Utility\\Capture.bmp >text.txt";
```

You can't use the redirection operators `<` and `>` with an ordinary command line to `CreateProcess`. The redirection operators are a feature of various command interpreters. If you want, fire up such a command interpreter, e.g. `cmd /c "mycommandblahblah > somefile"`.